# Java, Spring. Ошибка namedParameterJdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

Хотел изменить подключение на datasource, но столкнулся с такой ошибкой:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'namedParameterJdbcTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/NamedParameterJdbcTemplateConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate]: Factory method 'namedParameterJdbcTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/util/ConcurrentLruCache
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:657) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:637) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1176) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:405) ~[spring-boot-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
at cinemaWorld.application.main(application.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
```

Код:
SpringConfig

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("cinemaWorld")
@EnableWebMvc
public class SpringConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    public SpringConfig(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }
    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        registry.viewResolver(resolver);
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cinema");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("password");
        System.out.println("Успешное подключение через datasourse");

        return dataSource;
    }}
```

Контроллер:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/people")
public class PeopleController {


    private PersonDAO personDAO;

    @Autowired
    public PeopleController(PersonDAO personDAO) {
        this.personDAO = personDAO;
    }

    @GetMapping()
    public String index(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("people", personDAO.index());
        return "people/index";
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public String show(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model ) {
        model.addAttribute("person", personDAO.show(id));
        return "people/show";
    }

    @GetMapping("/new")
    public String newPerson(@ModelAttribute("person") Person person) {

        return "people/new";
    }


    @PostMapping()
    public String create(@ModelAttribute("person") Person person) {
        personDAO.save(person);
        return "redirect:/people";
    } }
```

DAO:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/people")
public class PeopleController {


    private PersonDAO personDAO;

    @Autowired
    public PeopleController(PersonDAO personDAO) {
        this.personDAO = personDAO;
    }

    @GetMapping()
    public String index(Model model) {
        // Получим всех людей из ДАО
        // Передадим их всех на отображения
        model.addAttribute("people", personDAO.index());
        return "people/index";
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public String show(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model ) {
        // Получим одного человека по ИД из ДАО и передадим ег она оторажение в представление
        model.addAttribute("person", personDAO.show(id));
        return "people/show";
    }

    @GetMapping("/new")
    public String newPerson(@ModelAttribute("person") Person person) {

        return "people/new";
    }


    @PostMapping()
    public String create(@ModelAttribute("person") Person person) {
        personDAO.save(person);
        return "redirect:/people";
    }
```

application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Изначально я дошел до использования JDBCtemplates в дао, но из-за этой же ошибки  стал пошагово откатываться назад. В конечном итоге пришел к тому что  при появлении datasource что-то идет не так. Как с этим бороться? Что исправить? Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Поправьте вопрос, вместо dao два PeopleController'a

Comment: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/util/ConcurrentLruCache` где-то версионная несовместимость скорее всего

Comment: Да, действительно проблема была в совместимостях. Spring-jdbc и spring-webmvc имели разные версии. Благодарю!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема заключалась совместимостях. Spring-jdbc и spring-webmvc имели разные версии.

Answer (score 0):

У меня была такая же ошибка, проблема заключалась в том, что на сервере был задеплоен компонент с более старшими версиями библиотеки Spring.
Помогло то, что я у класса NamedParameterJdbcTemplate распечатал откуда classLoader загружает:
namedParameterJdbcTemplate.getClass.getClassLoader().toString().
В распечатке было детально указано откуда берется класс, я сделал undeploy этого компонента и ошибка прошла.